# Conservation of Angular Momentum during a bike or motorcycle jump

Tags: classical-mechanics, education

I want to analyze the conservation of angular momentum during a motorcycle or bike jump (stopping the rotation of the wheels tilts the cycle and so on) and I have been desperately looking for some scientific / physics research on that, but only could find explanations with words, never calculations or models by using equations. Do you know of any scientific / physics research or books on this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say start with the subsystem level analysis: gyroscopic effect of turning the handles with the spinning wheels, effect of the spinning wheels on the angular momentum of the chassis and finally integrating both effects. You can start by reviewing[this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics#cite_note-Cossalter-9) and the analysis with the classic [Motorcycle Dynamics, Vittore (2006)](https://books.google.com/books/about/Motorcycle_Dynamics.html?id=1u_JkQEACAAJ). Additionally, I found [Wisel's book on spaceflight dynamics](https://books.google.com/books/about/Spaceflight_Dynamics.html?id=R0ZHAQAAIAAJ) on spaceflight dynamics useful for understanding momentum wheels and gyroscope dynamics, since that turns out to be the more challenging part of the analysis.